# net (TCP) module available in Node.app?

Tags: javascript, ios, node.js, tcp

*Can a Node.js application running on iOS via [Node.app](http://nodeapp.org/) utilize the [net module](http://nodejs.org/api/net.html) for TCP/IP communication?*

At the moment I don't have any Apple device to try that out myself.

Comment: According to [this](https://github.com/node-app/Nodelike#whats-working-right-now), yes.

Comment: @BenFortune Until proven wrong, seems that this is the answer, only I cannot accept it. ;-)